# Java PHP send text File to Server

Tags: java, php

I want to send a text file from a java class to php and store it on the server.
But the file never gets there

this is my java code:

```
public class JavaUrlConnectionReader
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://URL/upload.php").openConnection();
        httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        File myFile = new File ("/path_to_file/test.txt");
        byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        OutputStream os = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis= new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);

        System.out.println("Sending the file of size:"+ mybytearray.length + " bytes");

        os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);

        System.out.println("File sent.");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpUrlConnection.getInputStream()));

        String s = null;
        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        os.flush();
        bis.close();
        os.close();
        fis.close();
        in.close();
     }
}
```

and this is the php script

```
    <?php 

$target_path = "../output/"; 

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded"; 
} 
else{ 
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"; 
}


?>
```

It seems the text file never gets there.
I think the java code should be ok. I am doing something wrong in the php file.
Any help what's wrong with the php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way that I'm using to upload a file. May be it will help you.

```
        String postReceiverUrl = "http://URL/upload.php";
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

        //Create File
        File file = new File("/path_to_file/test.txt");
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);

        //Set up HTTP post
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart("MyTxtFile", fileBody);

        httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        if (resEntity != null) {

            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();

            System.out.println(responseStr);
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        }
```

**upload.php FILE**

```
<?php 

$target_path = "../output/"; 

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['MyTxtFile']['name']); 


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['MyTxtFile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['MyTxtFile']['name'])." has been uploaded"; 
} 
else{ 
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"; 
}


?>
```

Comment: Thanks. It is still not working. the text file is not saved on the server

Answer (score 0):

Seems you just prepare the POST parameters, and don't finally send the HTTP request.

I prefer using Apache httpcomponents-client library, here it's really easy:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        // Request parameters and other properties.
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        for (Entry<String, String> p : postArgs.entrySet()) {
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(p.getKey(), p.getValue()));
        }
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

        // Execute and get the response.
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            return instream;
        }
```